# Android check video stream ended

Tags: android, android-videoview

i've got this simple video stream player:

```
    if (play) {

                    myVideoView.stopPlayback();
                    myVideoView.clearFocus();
                    myVideoView = null;


                    button5.setText("Start");
                    play = false;
                } else {
//                  dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "Feldolgozás",
//                          "A videó töltődik");
                    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
                    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
                    progressBar.setMessage("A video töltődik ...");
                    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    progressBar.setProgress(0);
                    progressBar.setMax(100);
                    progressBar.show();     

                    myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
                    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams videoviewlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            500, 480);
                    videoviewlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,
                            RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    videoviewlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL,
                            RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    myVideoView.setLayoutParams(videoviewlp);
                    myVideoView.invalidate();
                    myVideoView.requestFocus();

                    myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            // mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                                public void onBufferingUpdate(
                                        MediaPlayer mPlayer, int percent) {

                                    progressBar.setProgress(percent);

                                    if (percent == 100) {
                                        //dialog.dismiss();
                                        progressBar.dismiss();
                                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        // "100%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                            mp.start();

                            // myVideoView.start();

                        }

                    }); 


                    play = true;
                    button5.setText("Stop");



                }
        }
```

How can i check if the video stream has ended or lost?
If lost the button should change to start and stop the videoview...
tanks for your aswers!

**update:** i think the problem is with the vlc rtsp stream because it says when the youtube rtsp is ended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the following listeners of `VideoView`:

```
public void setOnCompletionListener (MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l)
```

> Register a callback to be invoked when the end of a media file has
>   been reached during playback.

```
public void setOnErrorListener (MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener l)
```

> Register a callback to be invoked when an error occurs during playback
>   or setup. If no listener is specified, or if the listener returned
>   false, VideoView will inform the user of any errors.

[More Information](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

Comment: i've made a seOnErrorListener, but still the same, the app freezing and no error message or the toeast i made in...
just said the mediaplayer disconnected

Comment: how are you setting the `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: What do you mean as the "app freezing"?Is the UI blocked? 
Does the Logcat shows any error or message?

Comment: in freez i mean if push any button on screen(start/stop) it still be pushed and freez the app. nothing in the log :S